# How to add external jars in eclipse oxygen, so that they are automatically available to all other projects?

Tags: eclipse

I am learning spring framework.I am practicing in Eclipse Oxygen.

The website has given me 20 - 25 demo projects to practice and they asked me to import the required external jar files to each projects. The thing is that I have to add the external jar files to each project manually.( ie. I have to select the project => right click => Build Path => Add external jar files => select the jar files => Apply. Now I have to repeat these steps for each project).

I wanted to ask is there any way, that I can add these external jar jar files once in eclipse and they will be available to all of my demo projects ?

I am new to eclipse, I don't know whether there is some method for this or not, if there is it will greatly reduce my manual efforts.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this: via a user library (_Window > Preferences: Java > Build Path > User Libraries_), a project that exports the JARs that are included in the _Java Build Path_ by the other projects or via a build system like Maven or Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Put your jars in your local maven repository (`.m2` folder) and link to them in your maven script